# Assign Json file objects to variables

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON file that I would like to use with PHP to assign variables to the individual objects.

The file looks like this: (Is this a valid JSON file?):

```
{"draw":0,
    "data":[
        ["123456789",
        "first_data_one",
        "second_data_one",
        "third_data_one",
        "fourth_data_one",
        "fith_data_one"],
        ["7656576657",
        "first_data_two",
        "second_data_two",
        "third_data_two",
        "fourth_data_two",
        "fith_data_two"],
        ],
    "recordsTotal":"181",
    "recordsFiltered":"181"
}
```

I need some help assigning each values,

EX:  `number = "123456789", $first_data = "first_data_one", $second_data = "second_data_one", $third_data = "third_data_one", $fourth_data = "fourth_data_one", $fith_data = "fith_data_one"` to variables.
In the end I want to echo each, some thing like this:

```
echo Number: $number;
echo Number: $first_data;
echo Number: $second_data;
echo Number: $third_data;
echo Number: $fourth_data;
echo Number: $fith_data;
```

I want to put it all in a table in the end.

Comment: this is a datatable json. right? you dont have to parse yourself

Comment: Yes, a Datatables API

Comment: share your datatable code, you just have to return this json to datatable via ajax call,

Comment: `$('#myjson').dataTable( {
  "ajax": {
    "url": "api/data.json",
    "dataSrc": "data"
  }
} );`

Answer (score 0):

Your table header contains names for columns

```
<thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Number</th>
                <th>first_data</th>
                <th>second_data</th>
                <th>third_data.</th>
                <th>fourth_data</th>
                <th>fith_data</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
```

one way is to define columns, but then your return object based , columns as key

```
$('#myjson').dataTable( {
  "ajax": { "url": "api/data.json",
            "dataSrc": "data" } , // default datasrc is data, so no need of it
       "columns": [
        { "data": "number" },
        { "data": "first_data" },
        { "data": "second_data" },
        { "data": "third_data" },
        { "data": "fourth_data" },
        { "data": "fith_data" }
    ]
 } );
```

this will automatically assign data to columns 
the header will be your html header,
like you have 6 columns and your json also has 6 so it will be fine

```
$('#myjson').dataTable( {
  "ajax": { "url": "api/data.json"}
 } );
```

and if you switch on serverside processing
then you get these

> "recordsTotal": 57,   "recordsFiltered": 57,

have a look at the [api docs](https://datatables.net/examples/index)